# Display list elements using index of dictionary in Jinja(Django)

Tags: python, django, dictionary, jinja2

I'm using  Django Version 2.1.7,jinja2 and i trying to iterate list inside a dictionary using `forloop.counter0` in Jinja template.

MyCode **Views.py** :

```
 def sample(request):
    datas= ['value1','value2','value3'] #list
    data={'key1':'val1','key2':'val2','key3':'val3'} #dictionary
    return render(request,'index.html',{'datalist':datas,'datadic':data})
```

**Index.html (Jinja):**

```
{% for dic in datadic %} 
    {{ dic }}
    {{ datalist.forloop.counter0 }} 
{% endfor %}
<!-- datalist.0 is only possible after research ,but is it constant 
for every iteration -->
```

**Expected output :**

```
val1 value1
val2 value2
val3 value3
```

Comment: `data` is not a dictionary, it is a set. And the actual order of iteration over the set is undefined.

Comment: sorry , my mistake, its a sample data which i created , i will edit it

Comment: Are you sure you're using Jinja? `forloop.counter0` looks like the [Django template language for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for). The [jinja for loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for) uses `loop.index0 `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should zip your data within the view and iterate it once in the template.

```
zipped_data = zip(data.values(), datas)
return render(request, 'index.html', {'zipped_data': zipped_data})
```

...

```
{% for d1, d2 in zipped_data %}
   {{ d1 }} {{ d2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code 'data' is **set** and can not be iterated as **dict**. But in general iterations should look like this

```
{% for key, value_list in dictionary.items() %}
    {% for list_item in value_list %}
        {{ list_item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, actually i want to iterate list(which is pass in datalist) inside dictionary